# Specifying `curve` plot height?

Tags: r

I have the following code that generates four plots, but they end up squished (see image below). How do I fix this?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
curve(.5*exp(-.5*x),from=0,to=10,main="f(x)")
curve(.25*exp(-.25*x),from=0,to=10,main="f(y)")
curve(1-exp(-.5*x),from=0,to=10,main="F(x)")
curve(1-exp(-.25*x),from=0,to=10,main="F(y)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Three options:

1) Use `par(mar=c(bottom, left, top, right))` to specify respective margins.

2) Increase the total output size and it will automatically increase the plot size.

3) Use `ggplot` with `facet_wrap`, which will allow you to share axes to maximize space.